# Azure Devops Deployment Approval

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am setting a release pipeline with pre deployment condition that someone have to approve the deployment  . When I set that to one person that works very well ,and that person gets the notification email  .
If I set this to a group then members of this group do not get the notification emails .
I can still go an approve through the user interface but never get the emails .
Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> I can still go an approve through the user interface but never get the emails . Is there a solution for this ?

You could follow the document [Not getting emails from subscriptions or notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops) for some troubleshooting.

If above not resolve your question, you could try to add a new subscription An approval for a deployment is pending, the detail settings as below:

[image]

Just add the email address(es) who need to receive this kind of email, for multiple email addresses, separate with comma (`,`).